# CASE STATEMENT IN WHERE CLAUSE in QUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is as below

```
ID    |             email                 | ref
-------+-----------------------------------+------------
    12 | test@testmail.com                 |          0
    12 | test@testmail.com                 |          1
```

Now the requirement of the query is to retrieve the ID and the email where the reference is 0, however,
if the email is null with ref 0 then it should take the email value of ref 1.
If both ref has the email value then by default it should take 0.

I tried with the below query but it fails, it is giving me both the value

```
select 
    id, 
    email, 
    ref 
from 
    table1 
where ref in (case when email is not null then 0 else 1 end) and ID=12;
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your logic in mind below should give you the expected output

```
; with cte as 
(
select id, email, rn=row_number() over (partition by id order by ref asc) 
from table1 
where (email is NOT NULL OR ref=1) 
)
select id, email from cte
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, as per the requirement, however, I guess using cte is not good for the performance, but anyhow, I have to run this once in a day.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (email) t1.*
from table1 t1
order by email, ref asc;
```

This returns one row per `email`.  The row returned is the one with the smaller value of ref.

Note:  `distinct on` is a convenient Postgres extension to the SQL standard.  It is not available in other databases.

EDIT:

I think you may want one row per `id`.  If so:

```
select distinct on (id) t1.*
from table1 t1
order by id,
         (case when ref = 0 and email is not null then 1
               when ref = 1 then 2
               else 3
          end);
```

Comment: if suppose the email with ref 1 is null, then it will return both the values, however, the requirement is to return the only email with ref 0 and switch to the email of ref 1 only if the value in email with ref 0 is null